# How to handle the object before logging?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

Instead of this:

```
def log_error(obj):
  msg = do_someprocess(obj)
  logging.error(msg)
```

I want to add `do_someprocess` as a hook into logging. When I call `logging.error(obj)`, which executes `do_someprocess` before logging.

---

Background: The object is an error `object`, it contains error id and message, use `logging.error(error_obj)` to record the error. `do_someprocess` is for formatting error message of the object.

---

@mrEvgenX's comment gives me the idea that I don't have to make this as part of `logging`. so I am going to add `def __str__(self)` in my error class.

@Sam's answer also works as a different kind of solution, the Handler is `StreamHandler`.

Comment: I don't even know your context, sorry for saying this. If `obj` is a fancy object, other devs (even you a month later) could be confused "what a magic?". Very simple text and stacktraces - that's all what should be here. Complex processing is too much.

Comment: And so, you could simply write `logging.error(do_someprocess(obj))`, is better than hiding it behind custom LoggingHandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to create your own handler (create new class that inherits from one of python's handlers) and add it to your logger (this can be done once at initialization using AddHandler).

Please see
[Python's cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html) for examples.